# Django NoReverseMatch Exception error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have 2 views which after a post was made with the 1st view, I redirect it to the 2nd view with some parameters but I get this error, NoReverseMatch

```
def View1(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          #some back end codes here
          return redirect(View2, param1, param2)
     else:
          return render(request, 'View1.html')

def View2(request, param1, param2):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         return render(request, 'View2.html')
     else:
         return render(request, 'View2.html')
```

for the urls:

```
...
url(r'^View1$', views.View1, name='View1'),
url(r'^View2$', views.View2, name='View2'),
...
```

Here is the error:

> NoReverseMatch at /View1 Reverse for 'DJANGO.views.View2' with
>   arguments '(QuerySet [()], QuerySet [()])' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['View2$']

Comment: Can you post the full error, how did you link the view with an url?

Comment: I edited it, thanks for reminding with the urls

Comment: Well I think the problem is here that since the URL does not contain the parameters, you can indeed not construct such URL. The data needs to be encoded in the URL.

Comment: That is not the error. You need to show real code and the real error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by these lines of code:

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
return redirect(reverse("View2", args =[param1, param2]))
```